# Setting up the Bellman equations for dynamic programming

Tags: optimization, operations-research, dynamic-programming

I have the following question I want to understand.

> > The owner of a chain of three grocery stores has purchased five crates of fresh strawberries. The estimated
> >     probability distribution of potential sales of the strawberries before spoilage differs among the three stores.
> >     Therefore, the owner wants to know how to allocate five crates to the three stores to maximize expected
> >     profit.
> >     For administrative reasons, the owner does not wish to split crates between stores. However, he is willing
> >     to distribute no crates to any of his stores. The table below gives the estimated expected profit at each store
> >     when it is allocated various numbers of crates.
> >     Use dynamic programming to determine how many of the five crates should be assigned to each of the
> >     three stores to maximize the total expected profit. Start by giving the Bellman equations.
> >     $$
> > \begin{array}{c|ccc}
> > &&\text{Stores}\\
> > \text{Crates} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
> > \hline
> > 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> > 1 & 5 & 6 & 4 \\
> > 2 & 9 & 11 & 9 \\
> > 3 & 14 & 15 & 13 \\
> > 4 & 17 & 19 & 18 \\
> > 5 & 21 & 22 & 20
> > \end{array}
> > $$

Define $x_i$ to be the number of crates allocated to store $i$, and let $p_i(x_i)$ provide the expected profit from allocating $x_i$ crates to store $i$. Let $s_i$ denote the aggregated number of crates to be available for stores $i,i+1,i+2$ (for as far they exists). So $s_3$ denotes the number of crates for only store $3$; and $s_1$ denotes the number of crates for stores $1,2$ and $3$ together.

Per the solution: The Bellman equations (backward recursion) are now given by:
$$\begin{align*} &f_i(s_i) = \max_{0 \leq x_i \leq s_i} [p_i(x_i) + f_{i+1}(s_i - x_i)] \text{ for } i=1,2,3 \\ & f_4(s_4)=0\end{align*}$$

I understand the $p_i(x_i)$ part. As that is the direct profit associated with taking decision $x_i$. My problem is with the $s_i - x_i$ part. Why does this appear in the recursion formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it was already clear to you but... $s_i$ is the number of crates left in the inventory for $j$ remaining stores, thus it makes sense to subtract how many you have   allocated $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

$f_1(s_1)$ is the value of having $s_1$ crates left to assign to store 1. After assigning $x_1$ crates to store 1, the owner has $s_2 = s_1 - x_1$ crates left for store 2. Etc.

If this is too simplistic please let me know and I'll try to be more articulate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the maximum being taken over $x_i$ that satisfy $0 \leq x_i \leq s_i$ will help you understand. $s_i$ is the number of crates available to all stores whose index is $\geq i$. You can assign any number of crates $x_i$ to store $i$, as long as $0 \leq x_i \leq s_i$. And then you will have $s_i - x_i$ crates remaining to assign to the rest of the stores, starting at index $i+1$. The notation makes it so that the input to $f_i$ is always called $s_i$, and so this is how the $s_i$ are defined in terms of $s_{i-1}$ and $x_{i-1}$. Maybe that's the way to see how the recursive formula arises: Basically, whatever you pass into $f_i$ is called $s_i$, even though technically the $s_i$ are not explicitly defined recursively in your equations. And, deducing from the equations, $s_i$ is always defined as $s_{i-1} - x_{i-1}$, except for $i = 1$.